# Tuple comparison in Swift 3.0.1

Tags: swift, swift3

According to **The swift programming language (Swift 3.0.1)** iBook published by apple, comparison operators are applicable to tuples as well, as long as they do not contain Boolean values. So given following declarations

```
let t1 = (1, true)
let t2 = (1, true)
```

the following sentence throws an error as expected

```
t1 <= t2
```

Yet

```
y1 == t2
```

evaluates to true, which seem to contradict the aforementioned claim.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Fogmeister that would be `t1`, according to the generic implementation of the `<` operator for tuples of arity 2 :)

Comment: @hayordi Also, If you'd like to take a look at the `Tuple` source: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Tuple.swift.gyb
Notice that comparison (`<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`) requires the `Comparable` protocol and equality checking requires `Equatable` as pointed out in dfri's answer.

Comment: Your abbreviated quote *"comparison operators are applicable to tuples as well, as long as they do not contain Boolean values"* is misleading. –   The full quote from the Swift book  is (emphasis added): *"You can also compare tuples that have the same number of values, **as long as each of the values in the tuple can be compared.** For example, both Int and String can be compared, which means tuples of the type (Int, String) can be compared. In contrast, Bool can’t be compared, which means tuples that contain a Boolean value can’t be compared."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The type `Bool` *does* conform to `Equatable`, but not to `Comparable`

By the implemented Swift Evolution proposal

- [SE-0015: Tuple comparison operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0015-tuple-comparison-operators.md)

tuples up to arity 6 can be compared for

- equality (`==`) and inequality (`!=`), given that all the tuple member types conform to `Equatable`
- as well as the less or equal to (`<=`), less than (`<`), greater or equal to (`>=`), greater than (`>`), given that all the tuple member types conform to `Comparable`

Now, [`Int`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/int) and [`Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/bool) both conform to `Equatable`, whereas only `Int` conforms to `Comparable`. Hence, comparing the tuples

```
let t1 = (1, true) // inferred type: (Int, Bool)
let t2 = (1, true)
```

for equality/non-equality is valid, since both members conform to `Equatable`.

```
t1 == t2 // true
t1 != t2 // false
```

However, using the operators blueprinted in `Comparable` is not valid (since no such operators exists for `Bool`), as the 2nd member of both tupes has a type that does not conform to `Comparable`.

---

As to the OP:s comment:

> Seems logical. But the book lists comparison operators `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`,
>   etc. and then the claim. The official publisher is apple.

The operators blueprinted in `Equatable` (`==`, `!=`) are available for tuple comparison up to arity 6 given that all tuple members have types that conform to `Equatable`. This does *not* mean, however, that they have automatically access to the operators blueprinted in `Comparable` (`<=`, `<`, `>=`, `>`), since types may conform to `Equatable` but not to `Comparable`.

The `Comparable` protocol, however, inherits from `Equatable`, so if a tuple's members all conform to `Comparable` (for tuples up to arity 6), then all six comparison operators (`==`, `!=`, `<=`, `<`, `>=`, `>`) are available to that tuple, the former two via protocol inheritance from `Equatable`, and the latter four via `Comparable` itself (since types conforming to the latter must also conform to the former, by protocol inheritance).

Comment: And we have another gold-badge holder to close questions as duplicates!

Comment: @MartinR yes indeed \o/

Answer (score 1):

**Comparison operators** are different from **equality operators**. You can check tuples for equality by memberwise equality checks.

For some types, a comparison operator exists as well. However, that's not the case for boolean values. Which value should be greater, `true` or `false`?

Comment: Seems logical. But the book lists comparison operators ==, !=, >, <, etc. and then the claim. The official publisher is apple.

Comment: @Fogmeister actually, there is. See the linked proposal in my answer (as long as all members themselves conform to `Comparable`, the Swift devs compare the tuple members one by one in sequence: much like comparing two strings for inequality).

Comment: @dfri I just saw your comment. Checking it now :D